# Give colour to PHP string

Tags: php

Hello everyone I am trying one very simple thing but unfortunately for a reason that I don't get I can't have the desired result.I am trying to colourize a string everytime that is beign generated. I am running the example to an online interpreter and this is what I get back.

```
<?php
     echo "<p style='color:red;'>Hello Wolrld</p>";
?>
```

Result :

```
<p style='color:red;'>Hello Wolrld</p>
```

The whole thing is treated as a string from the echo which seems ok but I don't know how to structure or write it in order to get back the word Hello World in red.

Thank you very much

Comment: it works fine for me

Comment: That is really odd and not something I've ever seen before.

Comment: Are you launching this by doubleclicking the filename in explorer? If so dont. You need a web server for PHP to be interpreted and executed. PHP is not like javascript, it is not executed in the browser

Comment: Yes its working fine

Comment: What online interpreter are you using? It seems it is showing you the exact php output and not rendering any html. You should install a local server to test with.

Comment: what is the file extension `.php`

Comment: Actually I am trying to pass it as a value of a variable inside my code.Then I want to use the variable as a parameter of a function. However I don't get what I need, It is running on a live server I am not trying to the browser with my file.I tried here as well but no luck..http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/.

Comment: If file is not executed as PHP, the he would also see "<?php" and "?>" tags in output! It is OK to have output he has, but interpreter does not show it properly in browser. I would say, interpreter makes htmlspecialchars or similar.

Comment: The solution is simple: Don't run it in an external online interpreter. Instead install a local web-server and test with that. You will find that your code works fine.

Comment: @Panos sandbox online shows you what your code generate, shows source, not interpretes it as html

Comment: It works fine in http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: phpfiddle works fine thanks.Which is the right way to pass this as a value to a variable now in my php code and then use the variable as like as I want.can i use $test =  '<p style="color:red;">Hello Wolrld</p>';

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried that and still gets it as a string when I pass the $test variable as a parameter in a function.Maybe the declaration has to be made in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

Code works ok. Interpreter does not show PHP output properly, but shows HTML code encoded.

If you will try that code in your local server (XAMPP, or similar) it will work OK. It is a problem on interpreter side.